# Using server-side-render only for initial page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to use react's server-side-render to only get the initial state for the user. subsequent to that , i'd prefer to use websockets/ajax/client side routing to handle the application.

This is what i have so far

```
 function handleRender(req,res){

    getInitialState(id_token)
      .then(function(initialState){
        const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState)
        console.log('store.getState() ',store.getState())
        const html = renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
          </Provider>
        )
        res.send(renderFullPage(html,initialState))
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log('error')
      })
  }

  const renderFullPage = (html,initialState) => {
    return `
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Redux Universal</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="app"><div>${html}</div></div>
          <script>
            window.__INITIAL_STATE__= ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
          </script>
          <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>`
  }
```

my client side index.js is pretty much standard

```
const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__

export const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState)


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path ="/project" component={Project} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('app')
)
```

The above works well. when i navigate to /project on the client side. The Project component renders.

However , when i refresh the page at /project - i get a quick render of the / page before the client side router moves to /project.

Also , whenever i switch between routes , i hit the server again which i dont want.

i get that this should happen because refreshing hits the server again causing it to send back

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>
```

which renders the app component after which react-router renders the /project component again.

is there a way i can just get `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`  and initial HTML from the server without it having to send the html on every refresh/route change.

I do not want to hit the server on every route change which is what universal react does i believe.

The most important thing for me is to get the initial state for the user on page load. I prefer to have the app as an spa (only hit server for initial render/state and api requests)

Comment: Where is `handleRender` getting called?

Comment: "Also , whenever i switch between routes , i hit the server again which i dont want.".

Please clarify this point for me. SPA with the react-router and the Link from it does not cause the window to refresh and does not  " hit the server on every route change"

Comment: @idbehold - handlerender is set as an express middleware - `app.use(handleRender)`

Comment: @Yozi - the route change is hitting the server for some reason :( .. do you think its probably because i'm not rendering the router context along with the initial state?

Comment: @Kunkka, I think this may be a critical error or something like that, check it in console. Your client render looks correct, my about the same

Comment: Can you show the code for the `getInitialState` function? Also where does `id_token` come from?

Comment: turns out that chrome is sending a favicon request to the server on every route change :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're missing the part where you match the server-side requested route with what you have in your react router.

```js
import { RoutingContext, match } from 'react-router';
import createLocation from 'history/lib/createLocation';
import routes from './react-routes';

app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  // create a "location" object from the requested url
  const location = createLocation(req.url);

  // match the location to the react routes we have
  match({ routes, location }, (err, redirect, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).end('Internal server error');
    }

    if (!renderProps) return res.status(404).end('Not found');

    getInitialState(id_token).then((initialState) => {
      const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState);
      const html = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          {() =>
            <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
          }
        </Provider>
      );
      res.send(renderFullPage(html,initialState));
    });
  });
});
```

Check out [this isomorphic redux example app](https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app). Not everything will apply in your case, but check out the [server.js](https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app/blob/master/src/server/server.js), [client.js](https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app/blob/master/src/client/index.js), and [routes.js](https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app/blob/master/src/common/routes.js).

Comment: Wouldnt this essentially mean i hit the server on every url request? Even for /projects?

Comment: @Kunkka so long as you're using the `<Link>` element for navigation around your site then no. The `<Link>` element will use your react router to change the content on the page. It will not do a full page load unless you explicitly refresh the page or open a link in a new tab.

Comment: @Kunkka for example, if you opened a new tab and then entered yoursite.com/foo then your server would generate and send the HTML for that page. If you then clicked on a `<Link>` that went to /bar then you should see the address bar update to reflect that navigation, however you will not be doing a full page load. Monitor your network traffic and you will see that no request to yoursite.com/bar was made.